# How to open user profile in Fiverr App directly from android intent

Tags: android, android-intent, intentservice

I was wondering if there is a direct intent available in Android that can open a user profile in Fiverr App installed in the phone

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if fiverr provides that, I think opening web browser link by Intent.ACTION_VIEW is a good option, may be fiverr will open the application from the link in future.

I asked Fiverr Support team for the feature, This is Their Reply

> Unfortunately, this is not something we currently offer. In the future, should we offer such a thing, we will make sure to reach out to you and all the other sellers to let them know :)

Comment: Thanks... yes i knew that, but i was looking for an Intent if it was available

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no direct intent available in Android that can open a user profile in the Fiverr App installed in the phone. This is because Fiverr has not yet implemented this feature.

However, there is a workaround that you can use. You can open the Fiverr user profile link in a web browser and the Fiverr app should open automatically if it is installed on the phone.

To do this, you can use the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.fiverr.com/user/USERNAME"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Replace USERNAME with the username of the Fiverr user whose profile you want to open.

Note that this workaround may not work on all devices and may require the user to manually confirm that they want to open the Fiverr app.

I have asked the Fiverr support team if there is any plan to implement a direct intent for opening user profiles in the Android app. They have replied that this is not something they currently offer, but they may consider it in the future.